# Why does my Xbox One Controller stop responding while playing games on Windows 10?

Tags: controllers, windows-10

So I started playing Final Fantasy XIII - 2 via Steam the other day using my Xbox One controller and I noticed that whenever the game showed a prompt (i.e save game, play tutorial, anything in the blue dialog box) my controller would become entirely unresponsive.

The controller is connected to my PC via the Play and Charge kit, it is not setup to be used wirelessly.

The problem was temporarily solved by unplugging the controller for a moment* and plugging it back in.

*Too quick and it would remain unresponsive.

Is there any way to permanently resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive searching I came across [this posting](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_games/final-fantasy-xiii-input-freezes-on-saveload-menu/684231d1-de4e-47b4-be22-87c23eb198ed) on Microsoft's forum and it turned out that there had been a bug in the drivers at some point during the RC cycle for Windows 10 but was supposedly fixed.

Also note that the issue was reported to affect some other games as well.

Wading through the various responses on the post I found the following steps that resolved the problem:

> - Go to device manager
> - Select the Xbox Controller
> - Right click and select "Update driver software"
> - "Browse my computer for driver software"
> - "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer"
> - And then select "Microsoft Xbox One Controller" instead of the previously installed "Xbox Controller"

Comment: I'm using the official XBOX Wireless Adapter with my XBOX One controller. The only device I can find related to the controller is "XINPUT compatable HID device". I have exactly the same issue as the author of this question in FFXIII.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a wireless adapter to be able to play around with and find a solution. Given the problem for the wired controller I wonder if there is a specific Xbox One adapter that would resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Although not a real solution to the underlying issue, somebody has developed a hook for both Final Fantasy XIII & XIII-2. I have confirmed that the fix works for XIII (I don't own XIII-2) using a XBOX One Wireless controller via USB and via the official Wireless Adapter for PC.

The steam thread is here: http://steamcommunity.com/app/292140/discussions/0/487877107138721625/

https://github.com/d-b/final-fantasy-fixer

Simply ensure the fixer is running when you're playing, that's it.